# Spark random forest - could not convert float to int error

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I have features which are numeric and a binary response. I am trying to build ensemble decision trees such as random forest and gradient-boosted trees. However, I get an error. I have reproduced the error with iris data. 
The error is below and the whole error message is at the bottom.

> TypeError: Could not convert 12.631578947368421 to int

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
y = list(iris.target)
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/venky14/Machine- Learning-with-Iris-Dataset/master/Iris.csv")
df = df.drop(['Species'], axis = 1)
df['label'] = y
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df).drop('Id')
cols = spark_df.drop('label').columns
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = cols, outputCol = 'features')
output_dat = assembler.transform(spark_df).select('label', 'features')

rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol = "label", featuresCol = "features")
paramGrid_rf = ParamGridBuilder() \
                     .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, np.linspace(5, 30, 6)) \
                     .addGrid(rf.numTrees, np.linspace(10, 60, 20)).build()

crossval_rf = CrossValidator(estimator = rf,
                         estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid_rf,
                         evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                         numFolds = 5) 

cvModel_rf = crossval_rf.fit(output_dat)
```

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-44f8f759ed8e> in <module>
      2 paramGrid_rf = ParamGridBuilder() \
      3    .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, np.linspace(5, 30, 6)) \
----> 4    .addGrid(rf.numTrees, np.linspace(10, 60, 20)) \
      5    .build()
      6 

~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in build(self)
    120             return [(key, key.typeConverter(value)) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
    121 
--> 122         return [dict(to_key_value_pairs(keys, prod)) for prod in itertools.product(*grid_values)]
    123 
    124 

~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    120             return [(key, key.typeConverter(value)) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
    121 
--> 122         return [dict(to_key_value_pairs(keys, prod)) for prod in itertools.product(*grid_values)]
    123 
    124 

~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in to_key_value_pairs(keys, values)
    118 
    119         def to_key_value_pairs(keys, values):
--> 120             return [(key, key.typeConverter(value)) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
    121 
    122         return [dict(to_key_value_pairs(keys, prod)) for prod in itertools.product(*grid_values)]

~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    118 
    119         def to_key_value_pairs(keys, values):
--> 120             return [(key, key.typeConverter(value)) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
    121 
    122         return [dict(to_key_value_pairs(keys, prod)) for prod in itertools.product(*grid_values)]

~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py in toInt(value)
    197             return int(value)
    198         else:
--> 199             raise TypeError("Could not convert %s to int" % value)
    200 
    201     @staticmethod

TypeError: Could not convert 12.631578947368421 to int```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `maxDepth` and `numTrees` need to be **integers**; Numpy `linspace` procudes floats:

```python
import numpy as np
np.linspace(10, 60, 20)
```

Result:

```python
array([ 10.        ,  12.63157895,  15.26315789,  17.89473684,
        20.52631579,  23.15789474,  25.78947368,  28.42105263,
        31.05263158,  33.68421053,  36.31578947,  38.94736842,
        41.57894737,  44.21052632,  46.84210526,  49.47368421,
        52.10526316,  54.73684211,  57.36842105,  60.        ])
```

So, your code bumps upon the first non-integer value (here `12.63157895`), and produces an error.

Use [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange) instead:

```python
np.arange(10, 60, 20)
# array([10, 30, 50])
```